# Making plane with quad

Tags: unity, c#, terrain, joints

[image]I'm a beginner Unity 3d developer. I want to keep quads one aside another touching each other and use that as a road for making an endless runner game. The problem is each of the quads have their own box collider thus the car bounces a little bit sometimes.

Is there any way to get those stuff connected with each other and make the whole thing behave like a single plane?

I know using a big box collider covering all the quads in the repeating unit is gonna work but I don't want to use that.

Comment: Could you provide with a screenshot of your scene, so we get a better picture of what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: Ok, I have uploaded a screenshot.

Comment: If you hold V in scene view the gimbal (the three arrows thingy) will automatically snap to vertex points, allowing quick alignment of objects.  As long as all your road pieces are the same size and have the same collision size, this should be sufficient.

Comment: I already have all the pieces of the road aligned perfectly which has been showed in the picture. 1 single piece is set apart to show that the road pieces are perfect squares. This alignment is often causing some jerks which is causing an unpleasant driving experience.

Answer (score 1):

You might have these stutters with your car because of the collision update being to slow. You can try setting the collsion update mode on your car's rigidbody to continues dynamic or continues for smoother collision detection.

Another solution might be to not use the physics engine but instead make objects move in game code. In a infinite runner game like you are making now it might not be necessary to use the physics engine. Or at least not make the car move with physics and gravity.